# Python For loop only running for the last value of the input sql query

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, for-loop, pyodbc

Issue with the below Python script only using the last value in the query that I am using as the input to the first For loop. It should run for all employee id's returned and pull the photo from the api and insert it into a table.

I have had this script running where it has a manual input variable setup. But I am now trying to pull all the employee id's from a query and loop through them.

```
 import json
 import pyodbc
 import requests
 import sys


 InputconnStr = pyodbc.connect(
     "DRIVER={SQL Server};"
     "SERVER=TestSQL;"
     "Database=Intranet;"
     "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
     )


 inputcursor = InputconnStr.cursor()
 inputcursor.execute('select EmployeeID from Ciphr_Staging where DATELEFT is null or DATELEFT > getdate()')

 for row in inputcursor:

    # print(row)

    #user = row
    url = "https://hrsystem.com/api/PersonPhoto/{}".format(row [0])




 headers = {
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'Authorization': "apikey XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

 response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
 RTP = response.text
 RTP = "{\"PersonPhoto\": [" + RTP + "]}"
 data = json.loads(RTP)
 #data = json.loads(response.text)


 ID,Photo,PhotoDate,PhotoType = [],[],[],[]

 for device in data['PersonPhoto']:

     ID.append(device[u'ID'])
     Photo.append(device[u'Photo'])
     PhotoDate.append(device[u'PhotoDate'])
     PhotoType.append(device[u'PhotoType'])


 connStr = pyodbc.connect(
     "DRIVER={SQL Server};"
     "SERVER=Test2;"
     "Database=Intranet;"
     "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
     )
 cursor = connStr.cursor()

 sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Employee_Photo2 ([EmployeeID],[PhotoBinary],[PhotoDate],[FileType]) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"

 vals = [(int(device[u'ID']), device[u'Photo'], device[u'PhotoDate'], device[u'PhotoType']) \
            for device in data['PersonPhoto']]

 cursor.executemany(sql, vals)   
 connStr.commit()
 cursor.close()
 connStr.close()
```

Comment: The first loop's body simply assings a variable over and over again. Did you forget to indend the rest of the code?

Comment: I will have a look but I am presuming I have as the rest of the script does run. But only for the last value returned by the select query.

Comment: That presumption is wrong. The query runs just fine but the *loop* does nothing. Whitespace in Python is significant. The loop's boundaries are controlled by indentation. That means that the first loop contains only a single assignment and the rest of the code runs only once the loop finishes and uses the last value that was assigned to that variable.

Comment: You should break your code into separate functions instead of trying to put everything into a single loop. It's a lot easier to see what's going on with small, single-purpose functions.

Comment: It was the indents. It is working now. I am quite new to python. Thanks for the help and info.